# Remote work - good platform for future personal growth as software developer?

Tags: job-offer, telecommute

Currently I am working in small company as software developer (office work).

However, through contact with my ex-manager, and couple of interviews, I have received an offer for 100% remote work as a senior software engineer with relatively good salary and other benefits. Position is targeted to eventually take over all of software development from another employee who is mostly a hardware person (to become 'only' software developer). Company size is roughly ~200 employees.

To make my decision more difficult, I have also received an offer for another senior position at significantly larger company (~2k employees). This is standard office work, similar to my current company, but with potentially greater growing opportunities (for the fact of winning more contracts).

I have never worked as a remote worked (only once - half a year by efforts by my ex-manager at the present company) and never searched for it directly, and have gone though the process of getting an offer only by a direct recommendation to apply by my ex-manager. Given my lack of history and background with full-time remote work, can it actually provide growing opportunities which I would not otherwise get with a regular office job (specifically for software developing career)? I especially would like to hear from people that had both experiences.

Comment: Your last paragraph asks a question that is off-topic here; we can't tell you what you should do.  I would strongly suggest rewording to perhaps ask what are the skills you may learn from working remotely instead, or it is highly likely that the question will be closed as [off-topic](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2695#2695).

Answer (score 1):

A remote work situation requires a lot of self discipline, particularly if your work site is in your home. To be successful it really is necessary to setup a specific work space and treat it similar to how you go off to an office every day. Prepare yourself for the work session every day, try to keep a regular schedule, minimize distractions not related to work and try hard to maintain a reasonable work life balance. It is not uncommon for home life to take over the work environment or the other extreme where work intrudes into every aspect of home life.

Working away from your "group" of peers, leads and manager also has the disadvantage that you are largely only evaluated on your produced work product. Missed will be the various additional attributes that often make up a big part of an employee is evaluated as a valuable part of a team. Attributes that come to mind are leadership, mentoring and cross discipline work capabilities.

Another aspect of remote working is how you might feel about being left out of the "group" when various types of team activities happen. You also lose the ear to the communications channels that exist between people that work together.

So as to the choice of whether you go for the remote position or the new opportunity at the larger company it will really come down to how you feel regarding working in an isolated environment versus being directly associated with a group of people.

Answer (score 1):

> can it actually provide growing opportunities which I would not
>   otherwise get with a regular office job?

No.

At best, working remotely can only offer the same growth opportunities that you would get working in the office, not more.

More typically (in my experience), there will be fewer opportunities for growth. Attending meetings is more difficult remotely and leading them is even harder. Working with peers is harder. Being mentored and in particular mentoring others is more difficult. Being part of the office culture is more difficult. All the parts of communication that are non-verbal are far more difficult.

Again in my experience, while it's possible to overcome some of those obstacles to an extent, you risk being out of sight out of mind.

I've seen a few cases where an individual can grow in spite of working remotely, but I've never seen a case where the remoteness was an advantage in the same company.

The only possible opportunity that could open up would be with another company. Some other company may want to hire a remote worker, and may consider it a plus that you are already experienced in doing so.